# What is the difference between 未満 and 不足?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Both 未満 and 不足 have the meaning of [insufficient](http://tangorin.com/general/%E6%9C%AA%E6%BA%80%20%E4%B8%8D%E8%B6%B3) in JMDict. What is the difference in their usage?

Comment: Heh.. I always thought 未満 was more like "below, under, less than~"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

未満: it expresses **value**.  e.g. 20未満 means 'less than 20 years old'.  彼は友達以上恋人未満 means 'He is beyond a friend but not to the level of a boyfriend.'

不足: It expresses **status**.  It is necessary indeed, but it is insufficient now (and you would like to fulfill soon.).  e.g. 勉強不足 means 'you have not studied enough and you have to study more'.  ビタミン不足 means 'You have a sub-optimal level of vitamins' (because you have not taken in enough vitamins).